# how to change <li> text</li> in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
I am trying to replace a list element.
```

I was able to create node list, but was not able to convert it into a printable string. Does someone know how to print it?
I have already used home, but I am trying to retrieve the home and replace it with some text like home1. The id = "nav" is CSS id and once the list is received then I want to slice it and play with each list item. Like pointers list in C.

```
<html>
    <style>
             #nav {
                 position: relative;   
                 display: block;
                 margin-top: 0 10px;       
                 width: auto;
             }
             #nav ul {  
                display: block;
                list-style: none;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #nav li {
               display: inline-block;
               position: relative;
           }
           #nav a {
               position: relative;
               display: block;
           }
         </style>
    <body>
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>about us</li>
                <li>News</li>
                <li>complaint resolution</li>
                <li>contact us</li>
            </ul>    
        </nav>

    <script>
        function initt() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li"));
        document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML =  args;    
    }
    initt();

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

Any help will be appreciated.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't understand it, either. What is `x`? Why are you setting `args`, but never using it for anything?

Comment: I *think* that he wants to be able to replace the text in a specified item within the list.

Comment: I already tried this way <li id="item1">home</li>

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="item1">home</li>
            <li>about us</li>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>complaint resolution</li>
            <li>contact us</li>
        </ul>    
    </nav>

<script>
   function print() {
   console.log(document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML)
}
print();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming you need to acess the li element, you can give each element an id and then you can print